# access violation at render function c++ directx9

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, render, access-violation, directx-9

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <d3dx9.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

void initD3D(HWND hWnd);
void Render();
void cleanD3D();

LPDIRECT3D9 d3d ;
LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 d3ddev;


LRESULT CALLBACK MainWindowProc(HWND hWnd,UINT uMsg,WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(uMsg){
     case WM_DESTROY:
          PostQuitMessage(0);
          return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd,uMsg,wParam,lParam);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,  HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND mainWnd;
    WNDCLASSEX wndClassData;
    memset(&wndClassData, 0x00, sizeof(wndClassData));

    wndClassData.cbSize = sizeof(wndClassData);
    wndClassData.style = CS_CLASSDC;
    wndClassData.lpfnWndProc = MainWindowProc;
    wndClassData.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndClassData.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndClassData.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wndClassData.lpszClassName="ColourMatchingWindow";

    RegisterClassEx(&wndClassData);

        mainWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
        "wndClass",
        "ColourMatching",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        100,100,
        800,600,
        GetDesktopWindow(),
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);

    ShowWindow(mainWnd, nCmdShow);
    initD3D(mainWnd);
    MSG msg;
    for(;;){
    while(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL,0,0,PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    if(msg.message==WM_QUIT)
      break;
        Render();
    }
    cleanD3D();
    UnregisterClass("ColourMatchingWindow", hInstance);
return 0;
}

void initD3D(HWND hWnd){
    d3d = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);

    D3DDISPLAYMODE displayMode;
    d3d->GetAdapterDisplayMode(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, &displayMode);

    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;
    memset(&d3dpp, 0, sizeof(d3dpp));

    d3dpp.Windowed = TRUE;
    d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = hWnd;
    d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = displayMode.Format;
    d3dpp.BackBufferCount = 1;
    d3dpp.EnableAutoDepthStencil = TRUE;
    d3dpp.AutoDepthStencilFormat = D3DFMT_D16;

   d3d->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,
                      D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
                      hWnd,
                      D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,
                      &d3dpp,
                      &d3ddev);
}
```

//---------------------problem starts here-------------------------

```
void Render(){
    d3ddev->Clear(0, NULL, (D3DCLEAR_TARGET | D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER), 
    D3DCOLOR_ARGB(0, 0, 0, 0), 1.0f, 0);
    d3ddev->BeginScene();
    d3ddev->EndScene();
    d3ddev->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);  
    }
```

//------------------------problem ends-------------------------------

```
void cleanD3D(){
            d3d->Release();
            d3ddev->Release();
    }
```

VS2010 gave me the error message about access violation at **render()** , and I tried to debug the code, realised that error might be caused by d3ddev wasn't assigned to a proper value, but im quite confused by why it is't assigned a proper value and whats the logic behind it? I thought d3ddev would be created once **CreateDevice()** was called, but it isn't for some reasons.

Comment: But where is `d3ddev` initialized in the above code?

Comment: I assume it will be initialised automatically once i declare it

Comment: Think again. It won't.

Comment: is it because CreateWindowEx wasn't initialised properly?

Comment: Thats likely exactly where it is. Look at the windows class string name being passed to CreateWindowEx vs the one you just finished registering. The first parameter to CreateWindowEx should be `"ColourMatchingWindow"`; *not* `"wndClass"`. Start with that. And for the record, checking your API function results would easily have told you that call failed. Its a bad habit to ignore them, so break yourself of that habit right now.

Comment: okay I think I know why it didn't work ,since the parametre I passed indicated a totally different thing, so basically the system was trying to call the wndClass window instead of the one meant to be.